# Binding to property of a class derived from CollectionBase

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, exception, collectionbase

I am trying to bind some controls to an object - which is normally a pretty straightforward process.  Unfortunately, if the object that I'm binding to inherits from CollectionBase, binding to that classes fields causes the error:

> Cannot bind to the property or column Caption on the DataSource. Parameter name: dataMember

Removing the collectionbase inheiritance makes this issue go away, but I need this object to be a collection.  It seems as though CollectionBase causes higher level properties to become "unbindable."  Is there some property I can override to fix this?  Any other ideas?

I found this example online that summarized the issue pretty easily.  Unfortunately, I have yet to find an answer in all the places I've seen this example posted.

Code:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    TestCollection obj = new TestCollection();
    using (Form f = new Form())
    using (BindingSource bs = new BindingSource())
    {
        bs.DataSource = typeof(Test);
        f.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Caption");
        bs.DataSource = obj; // breaks

        //List<TestallData = new List<Test>();
        //allData.Add(obj);
        //bs.DataSource = allData;
        f.ShowDialog();
    }
}

class TestCollection : CollectionBase
{
    public string Caption { get { return "Working"; } }
}
```

Comment: Why do you set DataSource twice? First to type, then to instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CollectionBase` provides interfaces for a List of Objects, as such when used as a datasource the binding tries to look inside the list for the individual binding data.  When there is no list, you have a problem.

If you want a the caption and you want to use `CollectionBase` you should have 2 classes involved, not just one.

```
public class TestObj
{
    public string caption { get { return "yay"; } }
}

public class TestCol : CollectionBase
{
    //methods that implement CollectionBase for the TestObj type
}
```

with those two you can bind one of two ways.

```
TestObj obj = new TestObj();
TestCol col = new TestCol();
col.Add(obj);

//bind to obj, OR bind to col.  Both would work with this setup.
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.collectionbase%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

There is a sample implementation of `CollectionBase` there.

**UPDATE: EDITED FROM COMMENT**

There isn't any method that I personally know which allows you to bind to the outer properties of a collection.  As a workaround, you can use a 3 class system (yea, I know, more and more complicated).

```
public class TestHeader
{
    public string Data {get;set;}
}

public class TestCol : CollectionBase
{
    //...
}

public class TestObj
{
    public TestHeader header {get;set;}
    public TestCol col {get;set;}
}
```

bind the outer fields to `TestObj.header` and bind the collection fields to `TestObj.col`.  This is a workaround, but as stated I dont actually know a way to directly implement what you seem to want.  I wish I did, There are portions of my own code that would benefit from it.

**Another Example**

You could also do it with two classes, but you would still need to nest the collection itself

```
public class TestObj
{
    public string data {get;set;}
    public TestCol col {get;set;}
}
```

In this case, bind single data fields to `TestObj`, and collection fields to `TestObj.col`

Comment: Hi Nevyn,  Thanks for responding but I'm not sure that my question was clear.  In the Example "Caption" is a property for the collection itself - not an item in the collection.  Imagine a property like "Count" - this is what I'm looking for.  Another example: A class could be a collection of student objects but the class would also have a Name, and Time property.